# Android RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to implement a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` in my Android application. The `CardView` elements within the `RecyclerView` are displaying vertically as if they were in a `LinearLayout`. How can I coerce them to fill the grid from left to right, one row at a time?

Here is my `RecyclerView` layout code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RECYCLER_VIEW"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/item_offset" />
```

Here is my `CardView` layout code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="120dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the code to set up the `RecyclerView` in the activity's `onCreate` method (`CustomAdapter` extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`):

```
        // set up adapter
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ApplicationState.getGridElements());
        view.setAdapter(adapter);

        // grid layout manager with 2 columns
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        view.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // custom decoration for equal spacing
        ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getApplicationContext(), R.dimen.item_offset);
        view.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        view.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot ??

Answer (score 0):

```
GridLayoutManager (Context context, 
                int spanCount, 
                int orientation, 
                boolean reverseLayout)
```

Set reverseLayout as **true**